# HybridAuth Facebook not working on webserver, but running fine on local machine

Tags: facebook, hybridauth

I have setup HybridAuth authentication in my PHP Yii application.
Using Facebook for authentication is working perfectly on my local machine.

For my production server, i created a new app in Facebook and have accordingly updated the access credentials in my Yii app. But trying to authenticate from my live site, it gives the error that **Authentication Failed. Facebook returned an invalid user id**

If i rechange the credentials to that of my localhost and try it from my local machine, everything works again.

I am using the latest version of HybridAuth library 2.1.2.

I have already tried increasing the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false`, as recommended in some other answers at stackoverflow.

The local machine runs Windows7 and Apache whereas the webserver is running Linux and Apache.

Authentication from Google and LinkedIn are working fine on both my local machine as well as webserver.

Comment: The app configuration in Facebook should have sandbox OFF.

Comment: Well, at the moment I have removed Facebook sign-in from the application. Will check this option in a couple of days and get back. Thanks.